# Exporting Eclipse language highlighting

Tags: formatting, verbatim, eclipse

Does anyone know how to insert verbatim code from Eclipse? Not just how to include a file but also keep it's highliting, I use some not-so-widespread languages so exporting it directly would be neat and efficient.

Comment: What is the language of the code you want to highlight ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to export syntax highlighting directly, but you can use the `listings` package to highlight code, and it can be customized to new languages and new highlighting styles. [Here](http://texblog.org/2011/06/11/latex-syntax-highlighting-examples/) and [here](http://jevopi.blogspot.com/2010/03/nicely-formatted-listings-in-latex-with.html) are two examples of Eclipse-style syntax highlighting using `listings`.

Comment: Would print as pdf from Eclipse and inserting the pdf a solution? Or just a simple screenshot?

Comment: @samcarter That would cancel out the purpose of writting something to Latex.